# Possible to calculate % using following data?

Tags: php

My goal is to output a percentage to goal in a progress bar with the data i have below.

```
['b5','b4','b3','b2','b1','s5','s4','s3','s2','s1','g5'...'']
```

Start and ending can be picked out of that array. and then the calculation would be calculated based on where the % between the starting and ending variables.

Example:

```
Starting: b3
Current: b1 << Dynamic Updated from DB
Ending: s4
```

Result:

```
50% give or take.
```

Does that make sense?
I have seen this being done somehow using arrays but i am unsure so thats why i am giving this question to see if anyone has an idea about this.

This is based on Riot's Game API Data.

Thanks

Comment: Look to the values of the array keys, which are numeric.... and then it's simple mathematics.... (key current - key b3 / key s4 - key b3) * 100

Comment: I don't really get it, do you know how many elements there are between the starting and the ending element? Are you processing the values in a loop through this array?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it making any sense, but I'll try and offer an answer, so for a percentage we need a total and a value.
So I would take a 
[http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php][1]

and use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Which will get you the start/stop portion of the array.
Use array_search further to then find the index of the 'value' you are looking for.

Now you have total - length of the array and the index which you can use as the value.
Thus calc the percentage.

Is that helpful?